# ReactJs filtering results with .include() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filter

I'm trying to filter rows of a data table by typing into an input field, using `.includes()` function but it throws me an error of:

***TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined***

```
// Create variable for json data
        const countries = this.state.fullData;

        // Map through API results and create an object
        let rows = countries.map((countries, index) => {

            return (
                {
                    key: index,
                    country: countries.Country_text,
                    confirmed: countries['Total Cases_text'],
                    new: countries['New Cases_text'],
                    deaths: countries['Total Deaths_text'],
                    recovered: countries['Total Recovered_text'],
                }
            )
    
        });

        const getCountry = (e) => {

            const filteredData = rows.filter(countries =>
                //countries.country.includes(this.state.value),
                console.log('Countries list:', countries.country)
            );

            this.setState({
                value: e.target.value,
                dataSource: filteredData
            });
        }
```

However, if I console log out **countries.country** I see a list of countries as expected.

```
Countries.js:92 Countries list: Portugal<br/>
Countries.js:92 Countries list: Bolivia<br/>
Countries.js:92 Countries list: Panama<br/>
```

...

Thanks

Comment: According to your logs, `countries.country` is **one** value, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

`rows` is an array, by using filter on it you're iterating through each element in that array which is an object with all the properties assigned to it in the `map` method.

I'm assuming the property `country` is a string, and since `includes()` is a method used for arrays, using `countries.country.includes()` will not work.

`filter()` takes a predicate that should return either true or false, so what you have to do is

`const filteredData = rows.filter(countries => countries.country === this.state.value);`